# How do i get printer model via snmp in c#?

Tags: c#, printing, snmp

Basicaly what i want to do is retrieve hp's Printer Model from network printer via SNMP in c#.
Searching SO didn't yield anything usefull.

Where do i start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to either write an SNMP manager or use an existing library (there are plenty out there; [this is the one I use](https://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/snmp/), and [here's another](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SNMPDLL.aspx).) From there you'll poll the apropriate OID to get your printer model (you'll want to see the printer's MIB for that value).

Answer (score 2):

Download one snmp library and make OID as 1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.9.1.1.7.0 . You will get the printer name and Model