# How to get Zebra USB printer status from JAVA

Tags: java, printing, zebra-printers

My printer Zebra TTP 7030 is connected to local computer via USB.

I can print data using javax.print API but I cant get printer status or any data from printer.

I tried to get printer status from Java printService attributes but It does not return any valuable information about printer real time status.

```
Class<? extends Attribute>[] supportedAttributeCategories = (Class<? extends Attribute>[]) service.getSupportedAttributeCategories();

            for (Class<? extends Attribute> category : supportedAttributeCategories) {
                DocFlavor[] flavors = service.getSupportedDocFlavors();
                for (DocFlavor flavo : flavors) {
                    Object supportedAttributeValues = service.getSupportedAttributeValues(category, flavo, service.getAttributes());
                    if (supportedAttributeValues instanceof Attribute) {
                        Attribute attr = (Attribute) supportedAttributeValues;
                        attribSet.add(attr);
                    } else if (supportedAttributeValues != null) {
                        Attribute[] attrs = (Attribute[]) supportedAttributeValues;
                        for (Attribute attr : attrs) {
                            attribSet.add(attr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for (Attribute attr : attribSet) {
                System.out.println(attr.getName());

                System.out.println(service.getDefaultAttributeValue(attr.getCategory()));
            }
```

Zebra's Link OS SDK does not support my printer. Is there a way to get printer status?

**SOLUTION:** I used [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) to get Windows printer status for my zebra printer.

Here is example how to get printer information using JNA
[How can i get a printer's make and model in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476914/how-can-i-get-a-printers-make-and-model-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Zebra printers still work with ZPL you can send commands, just open up the virtual Com port and send the ZPL text based commands directly

(With the Z4000 and below it worked fine )
~HS
to get status.